# Voip Calling using sip_ua and flutter_webrtc

Tags: flutter, webrtc, sip

I am stuck with integrating sipua & flutter webrtc for making a voip calling function.
i have properly integrated the configurations with the private sip url n the pass keys but while hitting the call it throws an error strace like

```
I/flutter (24130): [2023-12-18 13:11:50.128] Level.error rtc_session.dart:2286 ::: Bad state: Future already completed
I/flutter (24130): #0      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:19:31)
I/flutter (24130): #1      RTCSession._createLocalDescription (package:sip_ua/src/rtc_session.dart:1708:17)
I/flutter (24130): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (24130): #2      RTCSession._sendInitialRequest (package:sip_ua/src/rtc_session.dart:2271:11)
I/flutter (24130): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (24130): #3      RTCSession.connect (package:sip_ua/src/rtc_session.dart:337:5)
I/flutter (24130): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (24130): 
I/flutter (24130): [2023-12-18 13:11:50.130] Level.debug rtc_session.dart:2952 ::: session failed
I/flutter (24130): [2023-12-18 13:11:50.131] Level.debug rtc_session.dart:2955 ::: emit "_failed"
I/flutter (24130): [2023-12-18 13:11:50.134] Level.debug rtc_session.dart:1448 ::: close()
I/flutter (24130): [2023-12-18 13:11:50.135] Level.debug rtc_session.dart:2966 ::: emit "failed"
I/flutter (24130): [2023-12-18 13:11:50.137] Level.debug sip_ua_helper.dart:235 ::: call failed with cause: Code: [500], Cause: WebRTC Error, Reason: Can't create local SDP
E/flutter (24130): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to RTCPeerConnection::createOffer: peerConnectionCreateOffer(): WEBRTC_CREATE_OFFER_ERROR
E/flutter (24130):
```

Can i get a solution for this or even if there is any sample project rather than the official sip_ua example or flutterwebrtc packages example, please let me know for reference.